# CentOS 7 - sshd: Permission denied on authorized_keys if the users home folder is on another partition

Tags: permission-denied, sshd, authorized-keys

I have an issue that drives me crazy... I try to fix it for at least 2 hours now - and I was not very successful.

Issue itself: 
I installed CentoS7 (I don't know if it's a CentOs 7 specific behaviour) on a VM that is supposed to host our git and gitolite environment. I installed required services and users. Everything is running fine and I'm able to conect via SSH with password and keybased authentication. All users have their home directory in /home/. 
Now, I would like to add a new user (git) with /srv/data/home/git (/srv is on a separate partition) as home directory and enable key based authentication. Both partitions are ext4 formatted.

```
grep git /etc/passwd
git:x:1000:1000::/srv/data/home/git:/bin/bash
```

I installed gitolite and created the user accordingly to the official documentation:

```
su - git 
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
mkdir gitclone-dir 
cd gitclone-dir
git clone git://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite
cd gitclone-dir
gitolite/install -ln ~/bin
gitolite setup -pk /srv/data/home/git/.ssh/git_admin.pub
```

Output of the gitolite setup command was:

Initialized empty Git repository in /srv/data/home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git/
Initialized empty Git repository in /srv/data/home/git/repositories/testing.git/
WARNING: /srv/data/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys missing; creating a new one
   (this is normal on a brand new install)

Next step includes a clone of the gitolite-admin repository which continuously fails:

```
marcel@mw-ws:~/Sources/juwimm_git/ayeq-benu$ git ls-remote git@192.168.10.35:gitolite-admin.git
git@192.168.10.35's password: 
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
fatal: 'gitolite-admin.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Please follow this link to see the whole debug3 log: http://pastebin.com/eiZSTu55

Most important lines:

```
Jul 18 17:45:40 bh-infra-s010 sshd[2739]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
Jul 18 17:45:40 bh-infra-s010 sshd[2739]: debug1: trying public key file /srv/data/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys
Jul 18 17:45:40 bh-infra-s010 sshd[2739]: debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/srv/data/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied
```

Now, I made some checks:

```
su - root 
cat /srv/data/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys 
# the statement above works fine and I see the files content on the command line 
su - git
cat /srv/data/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys 
# with the same result. It's working fine
```

I made some more tests. Find a summary of my testcases below: 
 - created an user with /home/testuser as home-directory, repeated the steps for the .ssh-directory and moved my pub key to it. Result: Working fine! 
 - created an user with /srv/testuser2 as home-directory and did exactly the same as above. Result: Permission denied on the authorized_keys file 
 - created a new user with /home/testuserls as home dir and repeated the steps for the .ssh directory. Now I created a symlink from /home/testuser3 to /home/testuserls and modified /etc/passwd to set /home/testuser3 as home dir for this user. Result: works fine! 
 - created a new user with /srv/testuser4 as home dir, put in the .ssh folder and created a symlink from /home/testuser4 to /srv/testuser4 and modified /etc/passwd once again to map his home directory to /home/testuser4. Result: Permission denied

```
ls -l /srv/data/home/git/.ssh/
```

This gives me:

```
total 16
-rw-------. 1 git git 1108 Jul 18 16:28 authorized_keys
-rw-------. 1 git git 1679 Jul 18 13:31 id_rsa
-rw-------. 1 git git  399 Jul 18 13:31 id_rsa.pub
```

I don't have any idea why this happens and how to fix this. Is it CentOS7 related? Am I blind or even stupid? Is this a new restriction from the ssh daemon in version openssh-server-6.4p1-8.el7.x86_64? I did not found any similiar issue on google or this side and was not able to find any solution... Any help would be really appreciated!

**UPDATE I**
All partitions (except for swap ofcourse) are formatted as ext4. The respective lines from /etc/mtab are:

```
/dev/vda1 /boot ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0 
/dev/vda2 / ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0 
/dev/vdb1 /srv ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

I don't use any ACL. Otherwise, it should be listed as mount options in the lines above, right? 
UID 1000 is the UID of user git.

```
grep git /etc/passwd git:x:1000:1000::/srv/data/home/git:/bin/bash
```

Let's check the permissions beginning at /

```
/srv: drwxr-xr-x. 10 root root 4096 Jul 18 16:48 srv 
/srv/data: drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Jul 18 12:25 data 
/srv/data/home: drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 4096 Jul 18 16:45 home 
/srv/data/home/git: drwx------. 7 git git 4096 Jul 18 15:30 git 
/srv/data/home/git/.ssh: drwxr-----. 2 git git 4096 Jul 18 16:40 .ssh
```

** UPDATE II - FIXED **

It turned out that selinux was activated. The issue was fixed by the following command on the .ssh-Folder:

```
chcon -R --type=ssh_home_t .ssh
```

Comment: What kind of file system is /srv on? Does it support ACL? Who is uid 1000? What are the permissions of all directories from root all the way down to the home directory?

Comment: @alvits Please take a look at the original post. I made an update to answer your questions.

Comment: `selinux` seems to be enabled. Can you run `ls -Z /srv/data/home`? You should see `user_home_dir_t` in the context. If it isn't there, you have to set it. The parent directory should have `home_root_t`.

Comment: ls -Z says unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 for /srv/data/home/git. So it looks like you're on the right way. Thank you so much for the tip with selinux. I never used this before. Unfortunately, hardened linux kernel were no topic at this company until now. It's one of the things I'd like to change. I will continue with the research on documentation about selinux. 
Can you tell me how to set the required user_home_dir_t?

Comment: You can use `chcon` to set context of path (directoies and files). You can also use `restorecon` to restore context. The utility is used in the same manner you would use `chmod`/`chown` utilities.

Comment: I would suggest you get the contexts from the working home directories and create a similar context in the new home directories `/srv/.../...`. This will ensure the you have the proper context. I should also point out that .ssh directory and its files have `ssh_home_t` context.

Comment: @alvits Thank you so much! It was fixed by chcon chcon -R --type=ssh_home_t .ssh (.ssh in /srv/data/home/git). I'm so happy to know that this is fixed now.

Comment: I'm just happy to have helped. :)

Comment: It's works on CentOS 6.5 too. Thanks!